# Submitting job for GP Service?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geoprocessing-service

I want to pass a feature service as an input(Input parameter type -GPFeatureRecordSetLayer) to a geoprocessing service. can anyone tell me a sample code? I read all the relevant questions available, but I didn't find an answer in which feature service is used as an input.

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: Are you essentially asking how do I pass a feature service as input to a geoprocessing service?

Comment: Yes.you are correct.

Comment: To-PolyGeo-I have edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find an example of this in the 3rd demo of the ZIP file from my presentation [Creating Geoprocessing Services UC2014](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=7e53061e6df64a0e89f3d7f1be194a49).

While this presentation is 5 years old and the **MapServiceIn_FSDraw.html** file references the 3.8 JS API, the patterns remain the same for the newer APIS.

Here's a cut/paste of some relevant code:

```
var inputLayerUrl = "http://xxxx.arcgis.com/xxxxx/arcgis/rest/services/Service/FeatureServer/0";

var inputLayer = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer(inputLayerUrl,{
      mode: esri.layers.FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
      outFields: ["reportedNumber"],
      opacity:.50
}); 

map.addLayer(inputLayer);

//use the map extent to select features
var selectQuery = new Query();          
selectQuery.geometry = map.extent;
inputLayer.selectFeatures(selectQuery, FeatureLayer.SELECTION_NEW);
//"Input_Features" is the name of the input parameter
params.Input_features = inputLayer;     

//Task (geoprocessor is assumed to be already setup)        
task.submitJob(params, taskComplete, taskStatus, taskError);
```